# While condition not getting terminated

Tags: javascript

```
if(childrens are present) {

   while(childrens.length ! ==0) {

            do something

    }
}   

// Execute this function fnName()
```

My problem here is the while condition is getting executed, but when the length becomes zero... it does not come out... and execute the fnName()

Comment: Post "working" code that demonstrates the issue, not pseudo–code.

Comment: must be about   `!==` . try < or >

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're actually removing children from the array in the loop, that should be fine other than that you've got the spacing wrong on the operator; it should be `!==`, not `! ==`:

```
while(childrens.length !== 0) {
```

Note that to actually remove children from the array, you have to use one of the array mutator methods, like `pop` or `splice`. My guess is that you're not doing that.

The more normal thing to do would be to loop through the array without mutating it:

```
var index, len, child;

for (index = 0, len = childrens.length; index < len; ++index) {
    child = childrens[index];
    // Use `child` for each child
}
```

Or using the new ES5 stuff like [`forEach`](http://es5.github.com/#x15.4.4.18) (which requires knowing your users will have a very up-to-date browser, or including an "ES5 shim" since `forEach` is one of the things that can be shimmed):

```
childrens.forEach(function(child) {
    // Use `child` for each child
});
```

---

Side note: The word "children" is already a plural (the singular is "child"), so there's no "s" on the end of it. Just one of English's irregular plurals (there are several).

Comment: FWIW, `while (ar.length ! == 0) ;` is actually a `SyntaxError`, rather than an infinite loop!

Answer (score 2):

The usual strategy is to create *childrens* as an array or similar object that has a consistent property that is checked on entering the loop, which continues while the condition is true.

In this case, it would be best to create *childrens* as an array, then decrement it in the loop so:

```
while (childrens.length) { 
  // do stuff to reduce the length of childrens
}
```

So when `childrens.length` is zero, the test is false and the loop exits (or if `childrens.length` is zero to start with, is never entered).

Answer (score 1):

For checking not equal to zero it should be

```
children.length != 0  // (you have written in the question children.length ! ==0)
```

If this is a typo the other problem might be you are not decrementing children in the while loop. Hence, it goes to an infinite loop.